# Search description misses search terms

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I've been retagging posts matching `[special] -character -[character] is:question`

The sidebar gives this helpful description of my query:

> results found not containing
>   and not containing
>   tagged with
>
> [special](/questions/tagged/special) not [character](/questions/tagged/character)
>
> search options
>   **questions only**

It looks like there are some words missing there...

Comment: I think the interesting combination of tag negations, and words that are both tags and terms, caused the engine to accidentally some of their descriptions. (I *think*. I'm not an SE dev; I'm probably wrong.)

Comment: All posts tagged [tag:special] should probably be retagged. Note that there is a [tag:special-characters] tag (which should definitely be preferred to [tag:special] and [tag:characters] separately).

Comment: @Dukeling: [I know](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195443/147400). I'm going through the ones which don't seem to match [special-characters] on a case-by-case basis

Comment: @michaelb958 [The only problem is non-tag negation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195472/bugged-display-in-search-using-negation). For your hypothesis, I suppose `-mail` is not a good example, as there is a [tag:mail] tag. But [the same goes for `-applepie`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-applepie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, negations *only* did indeed have some bad logic in there.