# Bugged display in search using negation

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

When you do [a search for `mail`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mail), it correctly displays as:

> results found containing
>   mail

on the right.

However, if you were to do [a search for `-mail`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-mail), it displays as:

> results found not containing
>   and not containing

Can this be fixed?